# Why does Automatic Updates service hang on startup with Windows 2000 Server?

Tags: freeze, windows-2000, windows-services, automatic-update

I have a Windows Server 2000 machine that has a popup on startup saying that a service failed to start.

In the Windows Event Log there is the following message:

```
System Log
Source: Service Control Manager
Event ID: 7022
Description: The Automatic Updates service hung on starting.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something worth noting here is that if the machine was up to date on July 13, you may as well turn this off completely.  [Windows 2000 server has reached end of life; new updates (including security patches) are no longer released.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2010/01/14/windows-2000-server-approaching-end-of-life.aspx)  Any security issues found as of the July 13 date will remain unpatched, and automatic updates no longer do you any good once the system is patched up to current.

That said, if the machine is not current you should at least get it there (really, though, it's time to retire this machine), and previously released updates should still be available.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Good point about the updates no longer being released. I've just patched the machine using Microsoft Update which seems to work ok.

I'm using the machine as a VM host running VMware Server, so the OS is adequate for my needs and means I can get by without an additional license for a newer version of Windows.

I'll disable the Automatic Updates service.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of error generally indicates that a service dependency has been broken.  In other words, something has modified service dependencies or startup timing so that the Automatic Updates service is trying to start before the services and/or components on which it depends have started.  Have you installed any software on the server recently?  One way to resolve this is to add a dependency to the affected service, which means that Windows won't try to start it until the depended-upon service has started.  There are other possibilities, including Group Policy configuration issues.  Does the service actually start, despite the popup?